# Script php : send mail using phpmailer

Tags: php, apache2, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a simple email using phpmailer.
I really have no idea if it's relevant since I'm just doing a php script, but I have apache2 & sendmail, apache2 running and sendmail include in the php.ini (sendmail_path=etc).

So here is my code :

```
<?php
$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = "<h1>Coucou</h1>";
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("totest@test.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('fromtest@test.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("totest2@test.com","First Last");

$address = "XXXX@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "XXXXX");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

//$mail->AddAttachment("./test.doc");      // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

So the thing is that my output is always "Message sent!", even if the script take a really long time to be executed (up to 10minutes !), but the mail never arrived to my mailbox (and I checked the spam folder).

Well I hope someone will have an explanation to that annoying problem!
Thank you anyway.

Regards,
Bdloul

Comment: Check your outgoing mail logs to see what happened.

Comment: Yeah I should have tought about that by myself. Anyway, it allows me to fix some issues, so thank you.